# ASP.net when i click a button i want to add rows from a grid view to a database but its giving me an error

Tags: c#, asp.net

ASP.net when i click a button i want to add rows from a grid view to a database but its giving me an error when i try to add more than one row but working fine with only one row.

The error it is giving me is System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Also when i click on the medication gridview to add the next row to the prescription gridview the first row of the prescription gridview gets deleted

Here is my .aspx file

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Doctor/Doctor.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DoctorDischargeForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="HWMS08.Doctor.DoctorDischargeForm" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <title>Discharge Form</title>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphContent" runat="server">
    <div style="margin-left:240px;text-align:left;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="#6F8C46" Text="Discharge Patient" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="25px"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Discharge Form" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="18px"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
            <div style="text-align:left" class="col">
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Discharge Date:"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="119px"></asp:Calendar>
                <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Discharge Time:"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTime" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTime" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <br />
                <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Discharge Condtion:"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCondition" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCondition" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <br />
                <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" runat="server" Height="21px" Text="Confirm" Width="92px" OnClick="btnConfirm_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is my .aspx.cs code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using BusinessLogicLayer;
using DataAccessLayer;

namespace HWMS08.Doctor
{
    public partial class DoctorMedication : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        BusinessLogic bll = new BusinessLogic();
        DataAccess dal = new DataAccess();
        string DrugName;
        int Row=0, Cell=0,scriptID;
        DataTable script = new DataTable();
        DataTable d = new DataTable();
        DataRow row;
        DataColumn column;
        DataView view;


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.IsPostBack == true)
            {
               

            }
            else
            {
                d.Columns.Add("drugname");
                d.Columns.Add("refills");
                d.Columns.Add("quantity");
                d.Columns.Add("note");
                Session.Add("script",d);
                dgvMedication.DataSource = bll.GetMedication();
                dgvMedication.DataBind();
                dgvScript.DataSource = bll.GetPrescription();
                dgvScript.DataBind();

                


                //column = new DataColumn();
                //column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
                //column.ColumnName = "drug";
                //script.Columns.Add(column);

                //column = new DataColumn();
                //column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
                //column.ColumnName = "refills";
                //script.Columns.Add(column);

                //column = new DataColumn();
                //column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
                //column.ColumnName = "quantity";
                //script.Columns.Add(column);

                //column = new DataColumn();
                //column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
                //column.ColumnName = "note";
                //script.Columns.Add(column);
            }
        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnAddDrug_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //string refill = txtRefills.Text;
            //string qty = txtQuantity.Text;
            //string note = txtNote.Text;
            //DrugName = Session["DrugName"].ToString();
            //script = (DataTable)Session["script"];

            //script.Columns.Add("drugname");
            //script.Columns.Add("refills");
            //script.Columns.Add("quantity");
            //script.Columns.Add("note");
            //row = script.NewRow();
            //row["drugname"] = DrugName;
            //row["refills"] = refill;
            //row["quantity"] = qty;
            //row["note"] = note;
            //script.Rows.Add(row);

            //dgvPrescription.DataSource = script;
            //dgvPrescription.DataBind();

            //dgvPrescription.Rows[Row].Cells[1].Text = DrugName;
            //dgvPrescription.Rows[Row].Cells[2].Text = refill;
            //dgvPrescription.Rows[Row].Cells[3].Text = qty;
            //dgvPrescription.Rows[Row].Cells[4].Text = note;

            //Session.Add("script", script);

            ////column = new DataColumn();
            ////column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            ////column.ColumnName = "drug";
            ////script.Columns.Add(column);

            ////column = new DataColumn();
            ////column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            ////column.ColumnName = "refills";
            ////script.Columns.Add(column);

            ////column = new DataColumn();
            ////column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            ////column.ColumnName = "quantity";
            ////script.Columns.Add(column);

            ////column = new DataColumn();
            ////column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            ////column.ColumnName = "note";
            ////script.Columns.Add(column);


            //if (txtRefills.Text != null && txtQuantity.Text != null && txtNote.Text != null)
            //{


            //    //row = script.NewRow();
            //    //row["drug"] = DrugName;
            //    //row["refills"] = refill;
            //    //row["quantity"] = qty;
            //    //row["note"] = note;
            //    //script.Rows.Add(row);
            //    //script.Rows.Add(DrugName,refill, qty, note);

            //    //script.Rows[Row].Cells[Cell].Text = DrugName;
            //    //Cell++;
            //    //script.Rows[Row].Cells[Cell].Text = refill;
            //    //Cell++;
            //    //script.Rows[Row].Cells[Cell].Text = qty;
            //    //Cell++;
            //    //dgvPrescription.Rows[Row].Cells[Cell].Text = UnitPrice;
            //    //Cell++;
            //    //dgvPrescription.Rows[Row].Cells[Cell].Text = note;
            //    //Row++;
            //    //Cell = 0;
            //    //view = new DataView(script);
            //    //dgvPrescription.DataSource = script;
            //    //dgvPrescription.DataBind();
                
            //}
            //Row++;
        }

        protected void btnRemoveDrug_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        protected void dgvPrescription_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void dgvPrescription_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            

        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            
            foreach (GridViewRow g1 in dgvPrescription.Rows)
            {
                
                scriptID = int.Parse(Session["scriptID"].ToString());
                if (g1.Cells[1].Text != null && g1.Cells[2].Text != null && g1.Cells[3].Text != null && g1.Cells[4].Text != null)
                {
                    PrescriptionDetail detail = new PrescriptionDetail();
                    detail.MedicationName = g1.Cells[1].Text;
                    detail.PrescriptionID = scriptID;
                    detail.Refills = Convert.ToInt32(g1.Cells[2].Text);
                    detail.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(g1.Cells[3].Text);
                    detail.ScriptNotes = g1.Cells[4].Text;

                    int i = bll.InsertScriptMed(detail);
                }


            }
            

        }

        protected void btnAddPrescription_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtStatus.Text != null)
            {
                DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["DoctorUserDetails"];
                int doctorID = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["DoctorID"].ToString());
                Prescription script = new Prescription();
                script.DoctorID = doctorID;
                script.PatientID = int.Parse(Session["DoctorPatientId"].ToString());
                script.PrescriptionDate = cldPrescription.SelectedDate;
                script.Status = txtStatus.Text;

                int i = bll.InsertPrescription(script);
            }
            else { }
            dgvScript.DataSource = bll.GetPrescription();
            dgvScript.DataBind();

        }

        protected void txtSearchScript_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table = bll.GetPrescription();
            //table = fill the table with proper values by accessing the database
            if (txtSearchScript.Text != "")
            {
                DataView dv = table.DefaultView;
                dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Name like  '{0}%'", txtSearchScript.Text);
                dgvScript.DataSource = dv;
                dgvScript.DataBind();
            }
            else if (txtSearchScript.Text == "")
            {
                dgvScript.DataSource = table;
                dgvScript.DataBind();

            }
        }

        protected void txtMedication_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table = bll.GetMedication();
            //table = fill the table with proper values by accessing the database
            if (txtMedication.Text != "")
            {
                DataView dv = table.DefaultView;
                dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Name like  '{0}%'", txtMedication.Text);
                dgvMedication.DataSource = dv;
                dgvMedication.DataBind();

            }
            else if (txtMedication.Text == "")
            {
                dgvMedication.DataSource = table;
                dgvMedication.DataBind();

            }
        }

        protected void LinkButton1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;

            GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;

            int rowID = gvRow.RowIndex + 1;

            if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)

            {

                DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)

                {

                    if (gvRow.RowIndex < dt.Rows.Count - 1)

                    {

                        //Remove the Selected Row data

                        dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[rowID]);

                    }

                }

                //Store the current data in ViewState for future reference

                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

                //Re bind the GridView for the updated data

                dgvPrescription.DataSource = dt;

                dgvPrescription.DataBind();

            }
        }

        protected void btnAddDrug_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string refill = txtRefills.Text;
            string qty = txtQuantity.Text;
            string note = txtNote.Text;
            DrugName = Session["DrugName"].ToString();
            script = (DataTable)Session["script"];
            
            
            row = script.NewRow();
            row["drugname"] = DrugName;
            row["refills"] = refill;
            row["quantity"] = qty;
            row["note"] = note;
            script.Rows.Add(row);

            dgvPrescription.DataSource = script;
            dgvPrescription.DataBind();

            dgvPrescription.Rows[Row].Cells[1].Text = DrugName;
            dgvPrescription.Rows[Row].Cells[2].Text = refill;
            dgvPrescription.Rows[Row].Cells[3].Text = qty;
            dgvPrescription.Rows[Row].Cells[4].Text = note;

            Session["script"] = script;

            //column = new DataColumn();
            //column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            //column.ColumnName = "drug";
            //script.Columns.Add(column);

            //column = new DataColumn();
            //column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            //column.ColumnName = "refills";
            //script.Columns.Add(column);

            //column = new DataColumn();
            //column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            //column.ColumnName = "quantity";
            //script.Columns.Add(column);

            //column = new DataColumn();
            //column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            //column.ColumnName = "note";
            //script.Columns.Add(column);


            if (txtRefills.Text != null && txtQuantity.Text != null && txtNote.Text != null)
            {


                //row = script.NewRow();
                //row["drug"] = DrugName;
                //row["refills"] = refill;
                //row["quantity"] = qty;
                //row["note"] = note;
                //script.Rows.Add(row);
                //script.Rows.Add(DrugName,refill, qty, note);

                //script.Rows[Row].Cells[Cell].Text = DrugName;
                //Cell++;
                //script.Rows[Row].Cells[Cell].Text = refill;
                //Cell++;
                //script.Rows[Row].Cells[Cell].Text = qty;
                //Cell++;
                //dgvPrescription.Rows[Row].Cells[Cell].Text = UnitPrice;
                //Cell++;
                //dgvPrescription.Rows[Row].Cells[Cell].Text = note;
                //Row++;
                //Cell = 0;
                //view = new DataView(script);
                //dgvPrescription.DataSource = script;
                //dgvPrescription.DataBind();

            }
            Row++;
        }

        protected void dgvScript_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            scriptID = int.Parse(dgvScript.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);

            Session.Add("scriptID", scriptID);
        }

        protected void btnEditDrug_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        protected void dgvMedication_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            DrugName = dgvMedication.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;

            Session.Add("DrugName",DrugName);

            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to search for the error message received? There are thousands answers about it. The problem is always the same, you are trying to convert a string to a number/date/decimal etc and the string has a value that cannot be converted to desidered data type.

Comment: Side note. Next time try to post only the code relevant to your error, not the whole page code behind and markup

Comment: i have looked at other answers about the error but the error isn't being caused by the wrong data type its being caused by the first row being deleted when i click a button which i don't know why it's happening